# Modifico y agrego ORDER BY `name` y no se guarda

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Soy nueva por aquí. Tengo una base de datos con categorías (skills) en mi base de datos. Está todo desardenado, y suguiendo muchos consejos de usar ORDER BY, cuando escribo lo siguiente SELECT * FROM skills ORDER BY `name` ASC al hacer click en continuar, se ordenó todo. Pero al refrescar la página phpMyAdmin, las categorias quedan todas, como estaban antes, desordenadas.

El formulario se sigue viendo igual, todo desordenado. Porque al hacer click en continuar, aparece todo ordenado, y después queda todo desordenado. Es como que no lo guarda, no se refleja en la página web.

Que hago mal? Hay algo en phpMyAdmin que debo activar para que se guarde por orden alfabético? O debo tambien hacer algún cambio en algún archivo?

La otra opción es ordenar todo alfabéticamente desde el php, es posible? Lo que deseo es que en el formulario, cuando se despliega, todo se vea en orden alfabético.

[image: Captura sitio]

En el archivo php que tiene los datos del formulario, encontré esto:

```
<select multiple class="form-control aiz-selectpicker" name="skills[]" required data-live-search="true" data-placeholder="Select required skills" data-selected-text-format="count">
                                    @foreach ($skills as $skill)
                                        <option value="{{ $skill->id }}">{{ $skill->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
```

Se podrá ordenar lo que trae de la base de datos?

Comment: Ejecutar una consulta SELECT no modifica la tabla. Tedrías que crear otra tabla con la misma estructura, insertar los datos ordenados en la segunda tabla y luego reemplazar los datos de la primera tabla con los datos de la segunda, que ya están ordenados

Comment: El código está incompleto.
Deberías mostrarnos de dónde se obtiene `$skills`, porque la clave está ahí... Cuando se obtiene (algún `SELECT` habrá), es ahí donde hay que añadir el `ORDER BY name`. 
De nada vale que veas la consulta un día ordenada si en el código donde obtienes las *skills* para la página no las ordenas cada vez que las muestras en el `<select>` o en el campo que pongas.

Comment: Podra ser esto: 

**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $categories = ProjectCategory::all();
        $skills = Skill::all();
        $client_package = Auth::user()->userPackage;
        return view('frontend.default.user.client.projects.create', compact('categories','skills', 'client_package'));
    }

Comment: Por tu ultimo comentario, parece que estas usando eloquent, por lo que te sugiero leer Eloquent [Retrieving Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#building-queries)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas intentado ordenar y guardar dicho orden de una tabla con un `SELECT` el cual se utiliza únicamente para **consultar**. (Imagina tener que organizar la tabla y guardar los cambios cada vez que hagas una solicitud. Esto insostenible)

Por lo tanto no importa el orden en el que estén guardado tus registros en la base de datos. Con la instrucción `ORDER BY` puedes organizarla  y no es necesario guardar este orden.

La solución
Debes buscar la consulta SQL en el codigo PHP y agregarle el `ORDER BY name`

Si no sabes en donde esta la sentencia SQL  y utilizas VSCODE puedes buscar en todos los archivos del proyecto  "SELECT * FROM skills"  y agregar el `order by name`

Comment: Wilfredo gracias por tu respuesta, todo más que claro. Lo estoy haciendo, pero no puedo encontrar en los archivos "SELECT * FROM skills" Estoy usando VSCODE y no encuentro nada, solo si busco skills me salen muchos archivos. Pero "SELECT * FROM skills" no aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Para una salida ordenada por nombres añade a tu consulta el `order by $columna` y así la tendrás ordenada, al momento de consumir bd datos solo tendrás que llamar a la ruta programada y listo.

Comment: Hola Camilo, gracias por tu ayuda! Y donde lo agrego?

Comment: Gabriela, añádelo donde tiene la consulta en tú bd, en el controlador, no se te organizará la bd pero siempre tendrás la salida ordenada

Comment: Camilo, si entiendo... pero que archivo será? Porque no sé cuál es el que hace la consulta en mi bd

Comment: No podría decirte donde si no veo tus archivos :(